# Why does the error appear when I add Json from Maven Repositories to POM in my project?

Tags: java, json, maven, pom.xml

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCqXF.png)]

This is the code I added

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20220924</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: missing `<dependencies>` in structure: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#dependencies

Comment: Please copy and paste the exception message as text rather than as an image -- that will help people find this question and any answers it provides.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/16702058)